# Any Record time AppExchange

Tags: apex, appexchange

Looking for Record time APP

-- Record hours to a unique contract for a unique account for a specific date
-- Ability to assign billable or non-billable
-- Ability to assign an invoice to the hours charged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Chrome, I recommend [TaskTimer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/task-timer/aomfjmibjhhfdenfkpaodhnlhkolngif?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) which will also work within Salesforce as an App. They offer a 30 day free trial and for single license Developers who run it in a Dev Org., they'll give you a free license with a limit on the number of projects you can keep open at any moment in time. Paid version doesn't have that restriction. Otherwise, consider rolling your own app based on something like the unmanaged version of [Simple Quote Invoice and Order](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TLtcEAG) as a part of what you'll need along with other code that's already out there from various tutorials.